# Get value of file input in iframe

Tags: javascript

I am building a website that loads an html into an iframe, and allows the user to change elements of that html through the parent page. One of the functions is an image upload that adds an image to a div within the iframe. I have the image upload button inside the Iframe but am trying to get the input type='file' on the parent page and maybe a getelementbyid(file)?

This is what I have inside the Iframe

```
 $(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
</script>

</head>

<body contentEditable="false">
<input type='file' />
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, there's no use of `contents()` or any indication that any of your code is accessing an iFrame, so what parts are where exactly ?

Comment: This is the function i have to upload an image. this is the html inside the iframe, but i am trying to place the <input type='file /> in a parent frame. And then get that element to load in the iframe.

Comment: Something like -> `$('iframe').contents().find('#myImg').prop('src', e.target.result);`